# Can I import a module from an integration test of another package in the same workspace

Tags: rust

I have a Rust workspace as follows:

```
|-- Cargo.toml
|-- p1
    |-- Cargo.toml
    |-- src
        |-- lib.rs
    |-- tests
        |-- test.rs
     
|-- p2
    |-- Cargo.toml
    |-- src
        |-- lib.rs
    |-- tests
        |-- test.rs
```

Can I somehow directly export `p1/tests/test.rs` so that it's functions can be used from `p2/tests/test.rs`?

I'm aware of the following alternatives, both of which I'd like to avoid because reasons:

- use the `#[path="../../p1/tests/test.rs"]` attribute with a `mod` in `p2/tests/test.rs` to create a new sub-module in `p1/tests/test.rs`.
- factor out common test definitions into a third, `test_utils` package

Answer (score 2):

Tests have access to dev dependencies, so you can provide a dev dependency in p2's `Cargo.toml`.  And you can define a [dependency from a local path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies):

```
[dev-dependencies]
p1 = { path = "../p1" }
```

Then in your `p2/tests/test.rs` file you can `use p1::*`

---

EDIT: Just realized that you want to export just the functions in `p1/tests/test.rs`.

If the test is an integration between p1 and p2, then a separate test file in the top level, outside of p1 and p2, sounds appropriate.

If you want shared utilities between p1 tests and p2 tests, then a 3rd package sounds appropriate.